# BigQuery Merge - Insert new rows if not mached

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a Merge query in Google BigQuery (part of an ETL process).

I have *Source* (staging) and *Target* tables and I have 2 ways of merge the data: the classic 'Upsert' Merge OR Insert new row if not matched all columns.

This is an example of the first way (the classic '**Upsert**') query:

```
MERGE DS.Target T
USING DS.Source S
ON T.Key=S.Key    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Col1 = S.Col1, Col2 = S.Col2
```

in that way if the key exist it always updates the values of the cols even if value are the same. also this will work only if the key is not Nullable.

The other way of doing it is to **inserting new row** when values not matched:

```
MERGE DS.Target T
USING DS.Source S
ON T.A = S.A and T.B = S.B and T.C = S.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ROW
```

I prefer this way, BUT I found that its not possible when column type is NULL, because NULL != NULL and then the condition is false when values are Null.

I can't find a proper way of writing this query and handle Nulls comparison.

It's not possible to check for Nulls at the merge condition, Ex:

```
ON ((T.A IS NULL and S.A IS NULL) or T.A = S.A)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ROW
```

Error message:

> RIGHT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

It's not possible also to use the Target table reference at the `WHERE` clause, Ex:

```
ON T.A = S.A
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND 
   S.A IS NOT NULL AND T.A IS NOT NULL
THEN
   INSERT ROW
```

What do you suggest? Also, lets say both ways are possible, what would be more cost effective by BQ? I guess the performance should be the same. I also assume that I can ignore the insertions cost. Thanks!

Comment: Would it work with `coalesce()`?  `coalesce(T.A, '') = coalesce(S.A, '')`.  Choose the default value appropriate for your data and the data type.  I also wonder if this would work:  `coalesce( x = y, x is  null and y is  null ) is true`.

Comment: You might also consider creating a surrogate key by hashing your unique fields together, then you can just do the upsert on that field.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a "magic" number or id?

This works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.target AS
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
  [STRUCT(1 AS A, 2 AS B, 3 AS C, 5 AS d)
   , (null, 1, 3, 500)
  ]);
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.source AS
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
  [STRUCT(1 AS A, 2 AS B, 3 AS C, 100 AS d)
   , (1, 1, 1, 1000)
   , (null, null, null, 10000)
   , (null, 1, 3, 10000)
  ]);
```

[image]

[image]

```
MERGE temp.target T
USING temp.source S
ON IFNULL(T.A, -9999999) = IFNULL(S.A, -9999999) and IFNULL(T.B, -9999999) = IFNULL(S.B, -9999999) and IFNULL(T.C, -9999999) = IFNULL(S.C, -9999999)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ROW;
```

[image]

Comment: that's a nice trick, but I prefer not to use it because I can't assume anything on the data, specially not magic numbers/dates/strings (e,g -999999)